# Can I use WireMock in Ionic Project?

Tags: ionic-framework, wiremock

I want to test my Ionic App and therefore I want to use Wiremock to mock the backend calls. Is this possible or can I use Wiremock only for Java Projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WireMock as a standalone process, as described in the [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/).In this setup it can be used in non-java ways as well.